# cumulatively concatenate columns in data.table by group

Tags: r, data.table

I have a data.table like the following:

```
x <- data.table(group = c('A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B'),
                row_id = c(1, 2, 3, 1, 2),
                value = c('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'))
```

I want to add a new column that cumulatively concatenate column 'value' ordered by 'row_id', within each group indicated by 'group'. So the output would look like:

```
   group row_id value
1:     A      1     a
2:     A      2   a_b
3:     A      3 a_b_c
4:     B      1     d
5:     B      2   d_e
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Several alternatives in the link. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24864073/1851712) is basically the same as posted below.

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to group by 'group', loop through the sequence of rows, get the sequence of it, use that as index to get the corresponding 'value' and `paste` together with delimiter `_`, assign (`:=`) it to update the 'value'

```
x[, value := sapply(seq_len(.N), function(i) 
     paste(value[seq(i)], collapse = "_")), by = group]
x
#   group row_id value
#1:     A      1     a
#2:     A      2   a_b
#3:     A      3 a_b_c
#4:     B      1     d
#5:     B      2   d_e
```